# PSPCMPROG and interface

Tags: peoplesoft

I want to get the code of different artifacts from PSPCMPROG, mainly classes and interfaces. Based on http://www.go-faster.co.uk/peopletools/pspcmprog.htm, I can use OBJECTID1, OBJECTID2, OBJECTID3 to get code depending on specific type. But I am unable to find how I can exclude (or include) code for interface, denoted by interface and end-interface and not Component interface. Do you know how can I do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the Decode PeopleCode project at https://sourceforge.net/projects/decodepcode/.  There are also derivative projects on Github as well, just search for "PeopleCode" -> https://github.com/search?q=peoplecode

Answer (score 0):

Each peoplecode type (as seen in the PSPROJECTITEM.OBJECTTYPE field) has its own particular mapping mechanism to the OBJECTID fields.  The best way to proceed is open some of the code of interest and save it in a project.  Then find the PSPCMPROG and PSPROJECTITEM rows associated with it and reason through the mapping at the OBJECTIDx and OBJECTVALUEy level.

For example:

- message pcode (objecttype 39) uses => **AND M.OBJECTID1 = 60 and M.OBJECTID2 = 12**.
- COMPONENT_INTERFACE_PEOPLECODE type (42) => **M.OBJECTID1 = 74 and M.OBJECTID2 = 12**.  I assume (without checking) that **OBJECTVALUE1 = PSBCDEFN.BCNAME**, where `Record.PSBCDEFN` stores `Component Interfaces`.

Generally speaking expect the 1st key for a record to map to **OBJECTVALUE1**, the 2nd to **OBJECTVALUE2**...

Note also that some of the tables storing plaintext, not binary, pcode, are not kept in synch automatically - there's an AE batch that does this, typically used during upgrades.  So make sure you are not pulling out stale data.  And you may have to stitch long programs together with PROGSEQ.